# How to disable system sounds in Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: gnome, sound, system-settings, 19.04

I am wondering how to disable system sounds in Ubuntu 19.04. Although I have them muted in system settings, as you can clearly see in the screenshot below, they still keep on making sound and annoying me:

[image]

Whenever a system sound disturbs my calm a new entry under system sounds appears briefly with full volume and before I can change the volume to mute it, it's gone:

[image]

Can somebody enlighten me, please, how to mute all system sounds in Ubuntu 19.04 or Gnome 3.32 respectively.

Answer (score 8):

This question has been answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1135983/234305)

> To disable alert sounds on Ubuntu 19.04 you could install dconf
>   editor, either from terminal or from activities/software center. From
>   terminal
>
> `sudo apt install dconf-editor`
>
> Next, launch `dconf editor` and navigate to
>   `org/gnome/desktop/sound/event-sounds` and flip the switch to `off` 
>  
>   alternatively, click on event-sounds and set custom value to `False`

Answer (score 2):

If sound files for system events are stored in `org/gnome/desktop/sound/event-sounds`, you could `mv` those files to a different location. for example: `.../event-sounds-backup`. Allowing you to easily put them back where the system expects them to be.

Or just delete the `event-sounds` directory if you're positive you will NEVER want to hear them, without having to re-install them.

Not an elegant solution, but no sound files means no sound can be played.

Comment: Disabling event-sounds work perfectly. Why risk deleting files ?

Comment: looks like OP was unable to simply disable them, the usual way. I offered two alternatives here. The first less destructive (moving/renaming a directory) then deleting them.

Comment: If someone doesn't want to hear alert sounds, ever, why take up storage space with the sound files they don't want played?