# Disable alert sounds in 19.04

Tags: sound, system-settings

According to [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sound-alert.html) page, which is written for 19.04, I'm supposed to disable alert sounds by switching the alert volume to off. However, if I go to Settings > Sound, I only see the following:

[image]

I see no Alert Volume setting. Any other way to disable the alert sounds?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Using dconf editor

To disable alert sounds on Ubuntu 19.04 you could install `dconf editor`, either from terminal or from activities/software center. From terminal

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Next, launch `dconf editor` and navigate to `org/gnome/desktop/sound/event-sounds` and flip the switch to `off` - alternatively, click on `event-sounds` and set custom value to `False`

---

### Using the terminal

From terminal without installing `dconf editor`

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound event-sounds false
```

Comment: in Jammy (22.04) just click on speaker button at the right of system sound setting under Sound Level part